# WebServiceContext or handle to session in JAX-RS implementation

Tags: web-services, rest, session

I'm trying to get session in the jax-rs web service implementation class.After reading many forums i found out that in AX-WS SOAP-based web service we can use WebServiceContext to maintain the state.

```
 @Resource
 WebServiceContext wsContext;
 @GET
 @Produces("text/plain")
 @Path("/hello")
 public String hello() {
   MessageContext mc = wsContext.getMessageContext();  !
        ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext)mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT);
        ...
    }
```

Is there an equivalent approch in jax-rs REST_based webservice to handle an object state in the session or any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext`

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext;
```

...
// add the attribute to your implementation

```
@Context 
private MessageContext context;
```

...
// then you can access `ServletContext` in your methods

```
ServletContext ctx = context.getServletContext();
```